# Algolia Javascript addObject non HTTPS

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm trying to add a new object to an Algolia index like this:

```
    var objects = [{
      firstname: 'Jimmie',
      lastname: 'Barninger'
    }, {
      firstname: 'Warren',
      lastname: 'Speach'
    }];

    index.addObjects(objects, function(err, content) {
      console.log(content);
    });
```

However I keep getting the following error message in console:

```
{message: "This method is only available in HTTPS", status:403}
```

I've modified the protocol like this:

```
algoliasearch('myID', 'myKey', {protocol: 'http:'});
```

But I'm still getting the same error message.

I'm running this in a browser instead of node.js but it's not a public facing website, only an internal admin dashboard.

So my question is, how can I get the Algolia `addObject` method to work with HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use:

```
algoliasearch('myID', 'myKey', {protocol: 'https:'});
```

So that you will use https.

Comment: Is it possible to use non HTTPS for this function? It's not a public facing site.

Comment: Indexing operations are only available via HTTPS, not HTTP. Is there any issue calling https endpoint from your http website?

Comment: Oh so it's possible to call the HTTPS endpoint from a non HTTPS website? Sorry I thought it wasn't possible.

Comment: Yes it is, try it